# How to get the cursor location during parsing?

Tags: c, parsing, packcc

I made a minimal example for Packcc parser generator.
Here, the parser have to recognize float or integer numbers.
I try to print the location of the detected numbers. For simplicity there is no
line/column count, just the number from "ftell".

```
%auxil "FILE*" # The type sent to "pcc_create" for access in "ftell".

test <- line+
        /
        _ EOL+

line <- num _ EOL

num <-  [0-9]+'.'[0-9]+     {printf("Float at %li\n", ftell(auxil));}
        /
        [0-9]+              {printf("Integer at %li\n", ftell(auxil));}

_ <- [ \t]*

EOL <- '\n' / '\r\n' / '\r'

%%

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    stdin = file;
    if(file == NULL) {
    // try to open.
        puts("File not found");
    }
    else {
    //  parse.
        pcc_context_t *ctx = pcc_create(file);
        while(pcc_parse(ctx, NULL));
        pcc_destroy(ctx);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The file to parse can be

```
2.0
42
```

The command can be

```
packcc test.peg && cc test.c && ./a.out
```

The problem is the cursor value is always at the end of file whatever the number
position.

Comment: `stdin = file;` doesn't work in many environments. See `man stdin` if you use Linux. Quote: "Since the symbols `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are specified to be macros, assigning to them is nonportable.  The standard streams can  be made to refer to different files with help of the library function `freopen(3)`, specially introduced to make it possible to reassign `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`."

Comment: Packcc provides the special variable "$0e" . If I use it instead of "ftell" the result is better, the cursor is stopped just after the token. But I get a wierd warning  " [-Wimplicit-int]" on the printf function, whatever if I use %d, or %li... That's why I don't answer my question yet.

Comment: Do you `#include <stdio.h>`? If not, you will probably get that warning (and some others). If that's not the problem, ask a new question with enough details to make it possible to answer without guessing what you did or what you saw when you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positions can be retrieved by special variables.
In the example above "ftell" must be replaced by "$0s" or "$0e".
$0s is the begining of the matched pattern, $0e is the end of the matched pattern.

https://github.com/arithy/packcc/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Without looking more closely at the generated code, it would seem that the parser insists on reading the entire text into memory before executing any of the actions. That seems unnecessary for this grammar, and it is certainly not the way a typical generated lexical scanner would work. It's particularly odd since it seems like the generated scanner uses `getchar` to read one byte at a time, which is not very efficient if you are planning to read the entire file.

To be fair, you wouldn't be able to use `ftell` in a flex-generated scanner either, unless you forced the scanner into interactive mode. (The original AT&T lex, which also reads one character at a time, would give you reasonable value from `ftell`. But you're unlikely to find a scanner built with it anymore.)

Flex would give you the wrong answer because it deliberately reads its input in chunks the size of its buffer, usually 8k. That's a lot more efficient than character-at-a-time reading. But it doesn't work for interactive environments -- for example, where you are parsing directly from user input -- because you don't want to read beyond the end of the line the user typed.

You'll have to ask whoever maintains packcc what their intended approach for maintaining source position is. It's possible that they have something built in.

Comment: I removed the plus signs on the first rule and the ftell functions gave the expected result.

Comment: @Ploumploum: Interesting. But then how do you parse an input with more than one number? (Rhetorical question; I'm not actually planning on using that parser generator.)

Comment: You have to use the Parser Expression Grammar principles. It's an alternative to EBNF. PackCC has an improved PEG because it supports left recursion. Something like: line <- (line _ num / num) _ EOL (not tested)

Comment: My previous post is wrong sorry, after some tests a working grammar is : test <-
    statement _ EOL  {puts("OK");}
    /
    _ EOL  then

statement <-
    statement _ num
    /
    num  and then you can parse lines with several numbers.

Comment: @Ploumploum: If you have a line with two numbers, both of them are reported at the same column position. But maybe that's good enough :(